# Do we need a checklist for [crc] questions?

Tags: discussion, tags, questions, tag-wiki, tag-disambiguation

I frequently see on SO questions about [crc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/crc) (Cyclic Redundancy Check), usually about buggy implementations. The same points frequently need to be clarified, and the errors found in the code are often similar across questions and languages. The problem especially frequently occurs with CRC-32, since there are two common CRC-32's, one called *CRC-32* and one called *CRC-32**C***.

Therefore I'd like to suggest the following:

1. That a checklist be added to the tag wiki, containing the following or similar:

> #### Have you checked:
>
> - **Which** CRC algorithm is being discussed? [List of CRC polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check#Standards_and_common_use)
>
>   - Be specific about the source of your CRC. If you're asking about the Ethernet CRC-32, say so. If you're asking about the Castagnoli CRC-32C, say so. Make sure to select the correct tag.
> - **Polynomial:** Is the polynomial correct?
>
>   - Is it bit-reversed?
>   - Is it byte-swapped?
>   - Is it complemented?
> - **Initialization:** Is the CRC correctly initialized?
>
>   - Some are initialized with all-zeros, some with all-ones, and some with something entirely different. Be sure to have the correct initialization.
> - **Processing:**
>
>   - Is the data being CRCed correctly byte-swapped?
>   - Are you using any CRC intrinsics, like Intel's SSE4.2 `crc32` instruction?
>   - Is your lookup table correct for the polynomial and byte-order you chose?
> - **Finalization:** Is the CRC correctly finalized?
>
>   - Some CRC schemes call for the polynomial result to be XORed with a particular constant, like `0xFFFFFFFF`, while some don't.
>   - The CRC output might be bit-reversed in your implementation.

2. That disambiguation tags be added for:

   - CRC-32 *(the family of CRCs with 33-bit generator polynomials)*
   - CRC-32 *(the specific CRC-32 with polynomial `0x04C11DB7`)*
   - CRC-32C *(the specific CRC-32 with polynomial `0x1EDC6F41`)*

   given that these two CRC-32's are by far the most used and asked about.

Comment: If you want to create a FAQ for [crc] questions then be sure to use the Q+A format.  It is a very small tag, do consider adding this to the tag wiki instead.

Comment: @HansPassant It's not really suitable for a Q&A. A lot of people write their own CRC(-32) for learning purposes, and come here to ask why their implementation doesn't match online calculators. Annoyingly, in 95% of cases it will have something to do with confusion about the specific CRC being implemented, a wrong polynomial, initialization, finalization or bit order. Providing a good CRC-32 implementation isn't useful here, and there's dozens to pick from already. Now if they had a checklist to run against, people could eliminate trivial issues by themselves and we'd see only trickier cases.

Comment: Perhaps Hans meant a Question like "What are the most common pitfalls when implementing a crc algorithm?"  and the answer being that table you posted?  It's not really a good SO question, as it's too open-ended and opinion-based, but might squeek by by virtue of being useful and having a good answer.

Comment: Maybe "My CRC implementation isn't behaving as expected.  How can I find out what's wrong?", in the style of the "What is a NullPointerException and how can I debug it?" or "Unfortunately MyApp has stopped" questions that are just debugging starting points.  It's not a typical SO question but if it's useful as a duplicate target, it will probably be kept around.

Comment: *'Some CRC schemes call for the polynomial result to be XORed with a particular constant, like `0` or `0xFFFFFFFF`'* - does requiring a polynomial result be XORed with `0` have much effect?

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist I just meant it said '*Some* CRC schemes...' - those that XOR with 0 are pretty much indistinguishable from a scheme that does not XOR at all. Perhaps remove the 0 example or use a different constant.

Comment: @abligh I've deleted the 0 example.

Comment: A CRC FAQ would be excellent.  Particularly if it included "Becuase you're trying to use a dsPIC33E CRC peripheral to do Modbus CRC-16" (if that's even possible then it's more trouble than it's worth) as one of the answers to why doesn't it work: that would have saved me many days of fruitless effort.

Comment: Not much point adding it to the Wiki as most people don't even read the snippit of a tag, let alone the wiki of one.  As others have pointed out, a Q&A would be more useful.

Comment: I've added the checklist to the tag wiki.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The checklist you've written here would make *excellent* material for the answer to a CRC reference question, along the lines of the [MySQL reserved words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23446377/syntax-error-due-to-using-a-reserved-word-as-a-table-or-column-name-in-mysql) question or the [regex reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean). Please write one! (If you do, drop me a comment and I'll happily upvote it.)

If you're not sure what to use as the "question", you may want to consider something along the lines of:

> My CRC implementation is giving me an incorrect result! What could be wrong?

Comment: Don't forget that a reference question still needs to be a good question in its own right.  The quoted question above would certainly not be.

Comment: @Joe Should I make my canonical answer a detailed answer to the SO question that prompted this MSO question?

Comment: @Joe Eh… depends. Since a reference question is a sort of standin for a wide variety of different questions, it'll by necessity be much broader than any of the individual questions would ordinarily be. Making it much more specific than the example I gave would risk making it too narrow.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think disambiguating the tags will be of much use. Those who know enough to correctly disambiguate might already know enough to not have to ask in the first place.